# volume-based physicsBodies being moved manually not contacting edge-based physicsBody

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

So in my Space Invaders game, all collisions were working perfectly until I added a physics body created from a `edgeChainFromPath` which is a single line to represent the ground (an SKShapeNode created from 2 points). Now my invader bombs (which move via SKAction) notify when they hit the ground but my invaders (moved in `update()` by manually updating their positions) do not. My ship missiles (also moved by SKAction) DO notify when contacting an invader.

Question : if a physicsBody is moved manually and comes into contact with another physicsBody, is `didBeginContact` not called? (All physics interactions - bitMasks, delegates etc - are set correctly). I'm thinking the answer is 'No it's not' because that's the only explanation and makes sense  picturing how Sprite/Kit probably works. I.e. A contact occurs when the SK engine itself moves a node and realises that it's physicsBody is being drawn on top of another physicsBody.

Edit - just realised that I have other physicsBodies in my scene that are stationary and that the invaders DO collide with, so it's not an SKAction thing. The difference might be that the new node I've added is an edge-based body belonging to an SKShapeNode, rather than a volume-based body for a SKSPriteNode, but nothing in the documentation that I can find states that this shouldn't work.

New question : Do volume-based bodies being moved manually not collide with stationary edge-based bodies?

Comment: Hi Steve, it's hard to help you if you use both SKAction and physics interactions/collisions (not recommended) , expecially if you involve the update method but without code I don't know so I could be wrong.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano - It's not what I though it was - see my edit. I've been adding bodies to this code and following a standard procedure - assign the category, set the bitmasks, add tests to didBeginContact and so far everything has worked first time, so my underlying code is good. I'm going to change the new edge-based body to a volume-based body to see if that changes things.

Comment: What's your current bitmask setup, are you filtering anything out in did begin contact?

Comment: All my bitmasks check out and my checkPhysics() routine tells me that the invaders contact the ground. The invaders make contact with other physics bodies that they are moved into and other physics bodies make contact with the ground. My current theory is that it's because the ground is a very thin edge-based body onto which a volume-based body is being placed directly, so I need to check this.

Comment: Manually moving will fire `didBeginContact`  The problem with manually moving involves collision.  Since the body has no idea on how force is being applied, it can't create an opposite force when you hit an obstacle

Comment: BTW, edge based physics are more expensive then volume based physics,  since you only have a line though, this may not be a problem

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yep - Changing to a SKAction.move made no difference. Something weird is going on...

Comment: Are you positive the physics interactions are set up correctly?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - no See my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - my bad. The invaders' physicsBodies had `dynamic=false`. Every other sprite was dynamic, so all other collisions were working. My new shape was an edge-based body which also are dynamic=false.

Made that one change and all is Ok. I need to update my `checkPhysics()` routine to test for this.

Edit: I really should have seen this earlier - `checkPhysics()` was not printing that invader notifies when contacting ground, which I just put down to a glitch that I'd fix later. Whereas checkPhysics() deliberately doesn't report on nodes with `dynamic=false`. I think that when I wrote the function, I assumed that you'd set dynamic=false deliberately to not be involved in collision/contact detection. I should change it to print a warning.

Comment: Note: Edge based bodies will always be `dynamic: false`

Comment: Indeed, but other sprites contacting the new edge body were dynamic=true. I just had to find the difference between my invaders and their bombs.

Comment: The SKPhysicsNode class reference docs don't seem to point this out.

Comment: An edge is a static volume-less body. Edges are never moved by the simulation and their mass doesn’t matter. Edges are used to represent negative space within a scene (such as a hollow spot inside another entity) or an uncrossable, invisibly thin boundary. For example, edges are frequently used to represent the boundaries of your scene. The main difference between a edge and a volume is that an edge permits movement inside its own boundaries, while a volume is considered a solid object. If edges are moved through other means, they only interact with volumes, not with other edges.

Comment: This means dynamic = false

Comment: Sorry - I meant that dynamic=false means that this body cannot generate a contact, not that edges are always false.

Comment: Annoying that Every. Single. Question. on SO about Sprite-kit collisions/contacts not working come down to the same old issues - the delegates, the bitmasks etc and I fall into the same trap... :-)

Comment: yup, it is a tough thing to verify because of how complex it is